# Is it possible to fire a HTTP request every time a PDF file is opened?

Tags: javascript, http, pdf, adobe

I understand there is support for JavaScript in Acrobat (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html) but have no further insight.

Comment: Sounds like something no end-user would want. If I regularly had PDFs that "phone home" I'd be looking for a new PDF reader that blocked it.

Comment: That aside you posted a link that has the documentation and theres a Net.HTTP method and various event callbacks. I'm sure if you combined them you'd get your result.